# AppArmor: make it ask me for decision to allow/disallow

Tags: security, apparmor

I'm having fun writing AppArmor profile for firefox.

I like to open downloaded files directly from firefox (by double-click on it), it is really convenient. But then firefox should have permissions to execute applications.

Say, for opening pdf files, I should write:

```
/usr/bin/evince rmix,
```

And similar rule for opening images, archives, etc.

But, I can't predict everything, so, one day firefox will be failed to open some file.

I can write something like

```
/usr/bin/* rmix,
```

but I don't like that. The best solution to me is to explicitly allow most often used applications (such as `evince`, etc), but for all the rest let AppArmor to ask me interactively. It is better than just denying or allowing.

Is that possible?